# using dictionary to find min temperature among cities

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to make a program that finds the minimum temperature based on the data given.
This is program I have so far, but it gives random results - sometimes max, sometimes min. Could someone please help me fix it.

```
d = {} 

for i in range(5):
    user = input("Enter city followed by temperature > ")
    if(user!='stop'):
        data = user.split()
        d[data[0]]=int(data[1])
    else: 
        break

alist=[] 

for k,v in d.items():
    alist.append((v,k))
    alist.sort() 
    t=alist[0] 
    print("The coldest city is:",t[1],t[0])
    print(d)
    break
```

Comment: please indent your code...

Comment: It will greatly help us if you could format your code a little better along with what you should be getting.

Comment: I indented the first few lines (those that I can be sure about) to properly format the code. Please fix the rest of your code. You can paste your code in the editor, select all code, then click the `{}` button on the toolbar to have it formatted correctly.

Comment: soory im new is this better?

Comment: To start off, why are you accepting in put in a loop ? You are overwriting the values

Comment: Enter city followed by temperature >Edmonton -2
   Enter city followed by temperature >Toronto 3
   Enter city followed by temperature >Vancouver -1
   Enter city followed by temperature >Ottawa -3
   Enter city followed by temperature >stop
   {'Toronto': 3, 'Edmonton': -2, 'Vancouver': -1, 'Ottawa': -3}
   The coldest city is Ottawa -3
   This is how the out put should look like

Comment: how else would i be able to input data into the program

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that after you get the data into the dictionary structure, you are appending this as tuples into a list and trying to sort the tuples. It's much easier to just sort the dictionary by value. Try this.

```
d = {} 
for i in range(5):
    user = input("Enter city followed by temperature > ")
    if(user!='stop'):
        data = user.split()
        d[data[0]]=int(data[1])
    else: 
        break
#Get an ordered list of tuples sorted by the temp
d_sorted = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]) 
coldest = d_sorted[0] 
print("The coldest city is:",coldest[0],coldest[1])
```

Comment: this is alot easier then what i was trying to do

Comment: is it possible to get a list of cities based on their decreasing temperature

Comment: @user2994135 Sure. After you get d_sorted, just add this line:

d_sorted_decreasing = d_sorted.reverse()

That will give you the list of tuples sorted decreasingly.

Answer (score 0):

Items in a dictionary are unordered. Their order may change from run to run. But your code (starting with `for k,v in d.items():`) takes the first value returned by `d.items()`, adds it to a list, sorts the *single-itemed* list, get the first and only value from the list, prints it and breaks the loop.

You could use `min()` function instead, to find the coldest city:

```
coldest_city = min(d, key=d.get) # find minimum in a dictionary by value
print("The coldest city is:", coldest_city, d[coldest_city])
```

You could use a simple `for`-loop, to find a key that corresponds to a minimal value in a dictionary if you can't use `min()` function:

```
it = iter(d.items()) # get an iterator over (key, value) pairs of the dictionary
minkey, minvalue = next(it) # assume dictionary is not empty
for key, value in it:
    if minvalue > value:
       minkey, minvalue = key, value
print("The coldest city is:", minkey, minvalue)
```

If the lowest temperature occurs in more than one city then any of them may be chosen as the coldest city.

Comment: i cant use min() function only dictionaries that why it is that much more complicated for me

Comment: @user2994135: I've added solution that doesn't use `min()`.